# OpenCV existing C++ code in Java

Tags: java, c++, opencv

I am trying to create java code by using existing C++ code. Please see [this link](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/highgui/video-input-psnr-ssim/video-input-psnr-ssim.html#videoinputpsnrmssim) for C++ code.

Everything looks fine expect arithmetic operations on Mat objects. I don't know what is java equivalent of those C++ code. I tried with google. I could not get anything regarding this.

```
 t1 = 2 * mu1_mu2 + C1;
 t2 = 2 * sigma12 + C2;
 t3 = t1.mul(t2);              // t3 = ((2*mu1_mu2 + C1).*(2*sigma12 + C2))

 t1 = mu1_2 + mu2_2 + C1;
 t2 = sigma1_2 + sigma2_2 + C2;
 t1 = t1.mul(t2);
```

Do you what is the java code for these. Here, the variables are Mat objects

Answer (score 2):

For addition you can use

[`add(Mat src1, Mat src2, Mat dst)`](http://docs.opencv.org/java/org/opencv/core/Core.html#add%28org.opencv.core.Mat,%20org.opencv.core.Mat,%20org.opencv.core.Mat%29)

And for multiplication use

[`multiply(Mat src1, Scalar src2, Mat dst)`](http://docs.opencv.org/java/org/opencv/core/Core.html#multiply%28org.opencv.core.Mat,%20org.opencv.core.Scalar,%20org.opencv.core.Mat%29)

See more option on OpenCV [Java Documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/java/org/opencv/core/Core.html)

Comment: thanks for the response, could you give me examples using sample code. that would be helpful.